# PHP practice without XAMPP installed

Tags: php

I just started learning PHP through online videos, I have also installed notepad ++ but I am not able to installed XAMPP due to security concern as I am using the company-provided laptop,

is there any way to do practice and run my PHP program without install XAMPP

Comment: You need a webserver to run PHP locally on browser. There are many online compilers like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php to test some simple scripts. But complex operations like database connection, session, etc cannot be done without XAMPP,WAMP, etc. So it is recommended to install it

Comment: php itself has in-built webserver. For small tasks it's rather suitable.

Comment: If you have internet, practice online or else use the built in web server by installing only PHP module and use `php -S localhost:8000` for instance. However, note that built in server is single threaded.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, PHP is a standalone program:

```
PS C:\> php -r 'echo PHP_VERSION;'
7.4.5
```

XAMPP is just a third-party package that bundles together several famous programs written by other people. You can always get any of those programs (PHP included) from each of the official web sites.

If you mean you want to use PHP to build web applications but you aren't allowed to install a web server, you may have a couple of options:

- Use [PHP builtin server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)
- Find out if your Windows edition includes IIS

If you mean that you aren't allowed to run any kind of third-party software, you're out of luck: PHP itself is software and it's third-party.

<sub>In any case: if your company is asking your to learn PHP, they should provide you with the necessary tools. If you're doing it on your own, know you're probably violating company rules anyway.</sub>